# Oracle Pivot and Pivot XML - ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

Am trying to perform pivot operation. Pivot is working properly. In in case i wanted to pass the query dynamically instead of hard coded values. According to documentation in used Pivot XML, but it providing error. Any suggestion would be helpful,

**Pivot working properly:**

```
select * from
(select  column_name from cols where table_name = 'EMPLOYEES') aa
pivot
(
max(aa.column_name)
for column_name in ('EMPLOYEE_ID', 'FIRST_NAME')
);
```

**Pivot XML throwing error:**

```
select * from
(select  column_name,  table_name from cols  where table_name = 'EMPLOYEES')
pivot xml
(
max(column_name)
for column_name in (select  column_name from cols where table_name = 'EMPLOYEES')
);

ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined
00918. 00000 -  "column ambiguously defined"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Tried providing aliases, but still its not helpful.

Do we have any other way to define sub query in IN clause

Comment: It's good programming to qualify all columns, at least when several tables are involved. I.e. do `cols.column_name` instead of just `column_name`.

Comment: Tried providing that, still its not working

Comment: @JimMacaulay . . . You need to use dynamic SQL for this -- that is, `execute immediate` in a PL/SQL statement.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, thanks for the suggestion, tried PL/SQL statement as you siggested and it worked. Below is the answer, someone might be helpful on this

Answer (score 1):

Tried using PL/SQL statement and result is as expected. Below is the PL/SQL statement,

```
declare 

v_Sql1 varchar(1000);
v_Sql2 varchar(1000);

begin

select  (LISTAGG(chr(39)||column_name||chr(39), ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY column_id)) into v_Sql1 from cols where table_name = 'EMPLOYEES'; 

v_Sql2:= 'select * from
(select  column_name from cols where table_name = ''EMPLOYEES'') 
pivot
(
max(column_name)
for column_name in (' || v_Sql1 || '))'; 

dbms_output.put_line(v_Sql1);
dbms_output.put_line(v_Sql2);

execute immediate v_Sql2;

end;
/
```